# Printing two table side by side on terminal with C++

Tags: c++, cout

I have a class for tables, and it has `display()` function to show a table object. However, in `main`, I have two objects, and I want to show these tables at the same line or level. My `display()` function includes nested `for` loops to show a 2D table. My problem is that when I call the `display()` function for the first table, it will print correctly but when I call the same function for the second table, it will print at the new line. I want to print them at the same line.

Example:

```
int main()
{
     Table t1, t2;
     t1.display();
     t2.display();
}
```

My output should be:

```
-----------------             -----------------
|       |       |             |       |       |
-----------------             -----------------
|       |       |             |       |       |  
-----------------             -----------------
```

But it is like that:

```
-----------------
|       |       | 
-----------------
|       |       | 
-----------------
-----------------
|       |       | 
-----------------
|       |       | 
-----------------
```

Is there any way to do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom solution. Sure it could be done better but this is a template for you to play with (and fun to write as well).

You can write a join function that takes the vector (or list as you wish) of tables and joins them line by line.

```cpp
std::string join( const std::vector<std::string>& tables ) {
```

First you create a vector `maxsize` to hold the maximum width of each table.
Then create a uber vector `joined` to contain all lines from all tables.

```cpp
    size_t numtables = tables.size();
    std::vector<size_t> maxsize( numtables, 0 );
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> joined( numtables );
```

Then loop through all tables, splitting every input as lines and pushing them into `joined`. Also keep the maximum number of lines for all tables as they dont need to be the same size.

```cpp
    size_t maxlines = 0;
    for ( size_t j=0; j<numtables; ++j ) {
        std::vector<std::string>& lines( joined[j] );
        std::string text = tables[j];
        size_t last = 0;
        size_t pos = 0;
        while ( pos < text.size() ) {
            last = pos;
            pos = text.find_first_of( '\n', last );
            std::string subs;
            if ( pos==std::string::npos ) {
                subs = text.substr(last);
            } else {
                subs = text.substr(last,pos-last);
            }
            pos += 1;
            lines.push_back( subs );
            if ( subs.size() > maxsize[j] ) maxsize[j] = subs.size();
        }
        if ( lines.size() > maxlines ) maxlines = lines.size();
    }
```

Then loop through the maximum number of lines, pushing the tables in order and appending to each entry the number of necessary spaces to pad.

```cpp
    std::ostringstream out;
    for ( size_t line = 0; line < maxlines; ++line ) {
        out << "| ";
        for ( size_t j = 0; j<numtables; ++j ) {
            size_t numchars = 0;
            if ( line < joined[j].size() ) {
                std::string text = joined[j][line];
                numchars = text.size();
                out << text;
            }
            if ( numchars < maxsize[j] ) {
                size_t left = maxsize[j] - numchars;
                for ( size_t k=0; k<left; ++k ) {
                    out << " ";
                }
            }
            out << " | ";
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
    return out.str();
}
```

The driver code looks like

```cpp
int main() {
    std::cout << join({table1,table2}) << std::endl;
}
```

Obviously you can do this with iterators as well to economize space. But that stays as a homework. It is easy to add formatting as you wish.

Suppose you have this input data:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string table1 = 
R"(asdf
sadf
asdfasfd
asdffds
sadf
f
asdfadsaa
)";

std::string table2 = 
R"(yuoiyio
yuio
yuiiii

yuoiyiooo
iuyu
)";
```

The output to the sample input above looks like:

```bash
Program stdout
| asdf      | yuoiyio   | 
| sadf      | yuio      | 
| asdfasfd  | yuiiii    | 
| asdffds   |           | 
| sadf      | yuoiyiooo | 
| f         | iuyu      | 
| asdfadsaa |           |
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/PM7KneYTn

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that both displays are using `\n` to separate the messages. Instead, you could define a `void display()` method and a `void display(char separator)` method, the first calling the second via `display('\n')` and the second would put `separator` at the end of each "line" rather than hard-coded `\n`, allowing you to do this:

```
int main()
{
     Table t1, t2;
     t1.display('\t');
     t2.display();
}
```

That would ensure that each line-end of `t1` would be a tab and each line-end of `t2` would be the default (`\n` in this case).

There is still a possible problem, when the number of rows differs for the two tables. You will need to figure out what you want to do in that case. It's quite possible that eventually you will end up separating `cout` display from the rendering at `display`, so you will return some string array from `display` and then assemble these displays in the way you like.